# Create users from AWS organizations in an account from it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-organizations

I created a script that automatically creates users based on inputs. My organization has many accounts, and to create users in a particular account I would need to enter credentials for that account. My question is if I could create a user directly from the AWS organization in a specific account. I did some research but couldn't find anything to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

No.  AWS Organizations is focused on organizing your account structures and SCPs based on OUs.  You can enable AWS SSO (now called AWS IAM Identity Center) to create users and give centralized permissions to your various accounts and OUs in conjunction with AWS Organizations.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/getting-started.html